# Как подключить Leemo/kohana-swift-mailer?

Tags: kohana, email

Всем привет!

Работаю в кохане пару недель. Знания в PHP маленькие. Очень хочу подключить swift-mailer для своего проекта. 
Можете описать подробно, как его подключить?
Хотя подключение описано в инструкций. Скорее всего мне нужно узнать, как его использовать. 
У меня есть основной template.php - статичный основной шаблон для отображения других страниц.

**Итак у меня имеются следующие страницы:**

- main.php (главная страница, где показан список товаров);
- order.php (страница с формой заказа);
- product-detail.php (как вы поняли, страница самого товара, в нем описание товара и опять та же форма заказа);
- contacts.php (страница с текстом "О нас" , контактные данные и опять же форма заказа).

В общем, вот. =) На всех этих страницах одна и та же форма. 
Можете, пожалуйста, описать до всех мелочей, до таких как "что писать в контроллере и в экшене". Надо ли создавать файл (для примера возьмем название forms) в папке messages?

[https://github.com/Leemo/kohana-swift-mailer#email-module-for-kohana-3](https://github.com/Leemo/kohana-swift-mailer#email-module-for-kohana-33)

Comment: Проверьте почтовый сервер.

Comment: не понял вашего ответа?